# How to use value from input id test_2 to innerHTML in id="show_text" as a onkeyup using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I not permission to edit in `function test_1_fn()` and input `id="test_1"`

So, how can i edit in input `id="test_2"` and `function test_2_fn()` to get value from input `id="test_2"` for `innerHTML` in `id="show_text"` as a `onkeyup` ?

Remark : input `id="test_2"` still `disabled`, and user can fill text into input `id="test_1"` only.

And this is not my homework. thank you for all advice.

```html
<input id="test_1" onkeyup="test_1_fn()"><br>
<script>
function test_1_fn(){
 var test_1_val = document.getElementById("test_1").value;
 document.getElementById("test_2").value = test_1_val;
}
</script>

<input id="test_2" onkeypress="test_2_fn()" disabled><br>


<script>
function test_2_fn(){
 var test_2_val = document.getElementById("test_2").value;
 
 document.getElementById("show_text").innerHTML = test_2_val;
}
</script>

<div id="show_text"></div>
```

Comment: Not really sure what you're asking, could you maybe re-phrase what your code should do and how it fails?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Also `test_2` is disabled, so any event handler on it is redundant.